Difference between FastCdr and Cdr? How to enable FastCdr in ROS2?
I'm working with ros2_humble, and I've noticed that the rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp package uses of eprosima::fastcdr::Cdr for serialization and deserialization but don't see any usage or mention of eprosima::fastcdr::FastCdr.
Similarly, in this link https://index.ros.org/p/fastcdr/ it's mentioned that in ros2_jazzy and ros2_rolling supports FastCdr package but don't see any usage similar to ros2_humble. Also, I don't see much difference in the implementation of fastcdr and cdr.
My queries are:

How is the FastCdr implementation mechanism faster than standard Cdr?

How to enable FastCdr class usage?


